# Reduce opencv4 dynamic lib .so size

Tags: android, c++, opencv, clang

I'm trying to reduce .so file size for an android app, but when I recompile the dynamic library my app crashes with this code

```
java.lang.UnsatisfiedLinkError: No implementation found for long org.opencv.core.Mat.n_Mat() (tried Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat and Java_org_opencv_core_Mat_n_1Mat__).
```

I'm also tried to recompile from src, but for some reason, when I add modify the root CMakeLists.txt file (line 153 at this time), the compilation fails because doesn't find a file from samples.

Here is my command to recompile .so from static libraries for arm64

```
$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/bin/clang++  -fpic --sysroot=$ANDROID_NDK_ROOT/toolchains/llvm/prebuilt/darwin-x86_64/sysroot -target aarch64-linux-android21 -shared -Xlinker -soname=libopencv_java4.so -o libopencv_java4.so -Xlinker --no-as-needed -Xlinker --whole-archive -Xlinker libcpufeatures.a -Xlinker libIlmImf.a -Xlinker liblibjasper.a -Xlinker liblibjpeg-turbo.a -Xlinker liblibpng.a -Xlinker liblibprotobuf.a -Xlinker liblibtiff.a -Xlinker liblibwebp.a -Xlinker libquirc.a -Xlinker libtbb.a -Xlinker libtegra_hal.a -Xlinker libopencv_imgcodecs.a -Xlinker libopencv_imgproc.a -Xlinker libopencv_core.a -Xlinker --no-whole-archive -nostdlib++ -llog -ljnigraphics -landroid -lmediandk -lz
```

generated .so info

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x9fabc8 contains 33 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjnigraphics.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libandroid.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmediandk.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libopencv_java4.so]
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x9e4948
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       216 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x9e4a20
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x1c8
 0x000000006ffffef5 (GNU_HASH)           0x5378
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x1d230
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0xa8d0
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              121597 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0xa0ae18
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           27888 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0xb0260
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x3c658
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             474120 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x3c5f8
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         3
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x3ad2e
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          16950
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

original .so info

```
Dynamic section at offset 0x116d898 contains 32 entries:
  Tag        Type                         Name/Value
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libdl.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libm.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [liblog.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libjnigraphics.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libz.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libc.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libandroid.so]
 0x0000000000000001 (NEEDED)             Shared library: [libmediandk.so]
 0x000000000000000e (SONAME)             Library soname: [libopencv_java4.so]
 0x0000000000000019 (INIT_ARRAY)         0x11378f0
 0x000000000000001b (INIT_ARRAYSZ)       384 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001a (FINI_ARRAY)         0x1137a70
 0x000000000000001c (FINI_ARRAYSZ)       16 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000004 (HASH)               0x228
 0x0000000000000005 (STRTAB)             0x3b328
 0x0000000000000006 (SYMTAB)             0xc018
 0x000000000000000a (STRSZ)              372415 (bytes)
 0x000000000000000b (SYMENT)             24 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000003 (PLTGOT)             0x117dad8
 0x0000000000000002 (PLTRELSZ)           49488 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000014 (PLTREL)             RELA
 0x0000000000000017 (JMPREL)             0x161668
 0x0000000000000007 (RELA)               0x9a138
 0x0000000000000008 (RELASZ)             816432 (bytes)
 0x0000000000000009 (RELAENT)            24 (bytes)
 0x000000000000001e (FLAGS)              BIND_NOW
 0x000000006ffffffb (FLAGS_1)            Flags: NOW
 0x000000006ffffffe (VERNEED)            0x9a0d8
 0x000000006fffffff (VERNEEDNUM)         3
 0x000000006ffffff0 (VERSYM)             0x961e8
 0x000000006ffffff9 (RELACOUNT)          26157
 0x0000000000000000 (NULL)               0x0
```

Answer (score 1):

Ok, finally I reduced the size of opencv via build_sdk.py script, just added BUILD_LIST="core,imgproc,imgcodecs,java", to the cmake_vars dictionary in build_library function, also I'm disabled the INSTALL_ANDROID_EXAMPLES to "OFF", and passed the --no_samples_build flag as command line option

Comment: To future readers: a new command-line option, `--modules_list core,imgproc,imgcodecs,java`, [has been introduced to `build_sdk.py` in OpenCV 3.4.10 (2020)](http://github.com/opencv/opencv/commit/814a5cec414858ddbe7ae54da4535529cb712377) and later versions.